# How can i solve this statement

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm downloaded a template for my asp.net website. The templates is for Joomla CMS. I converted all but I have some problem in the header and can't understand what does it do and how can I specialize for asp.net:

```
    <jdoc:include type="head" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ;?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ;?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ;?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ;?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" /> 
<!--<?php if($this->direction == 'rtl') : ?> -->
 <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ;?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ;?>/css/template_rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
 <?php endif; ?> 
 <!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

 <link id="JTKLocalCss" href="css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the code `<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/` with `<% = this.ResolveUrl("~/") %>`

For the code `<?php echo $this->template ?>`, replace it with `<% = this.ResolveUrl("~/") %>` and then you must define a Template accessor in the codebehind:

```
protected string Template { get; set; }
```

This will then need to be set (e.g. on PageLoad) for the property to populate the code above.

For the `<?php if($this->direction == 'rtl') : ?> ... <?php endif; ?>` statement, this can be replaced with:

```
<% if(this.Direction) {%>...<%}%>
```

Again this will need an accessor in the codebehind, much like the Template example.

Answer (score 0):

Most of it is stylesheet linking. It allows the user to have an external styleseeht. Where it says php echo... this is basically a link to the base URL. You don't need those in and can replace with ~/

Comment: This won't work unless the code is within a <head runat="server"> element or if the <link> has a runat="server" attribute.

Comment: thank you my friend but i thought it is a way to configure web page for another browser like IE or safari or opera. the main problem that i always have in web design is when make my content to be center with margin:auto; statement its only become center in Fire fox and not perform in IE what can i do for this???!!

Comment: thanks digbyswift hadn't thought of adding this in. That is really a different question hussein. It would be much easier to either write the template yourself and learn more or get a template that is native html and avoid Joomla templates for all but joomla.

Comment: No body could tell me how can i set element in center at IE, in firefox i use to write this statement : Margin:auto;

Comment: We can if you ask it in the question. margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto should be fine cross browser

Comment: i did it but it doesn't set my element center in IE

Comment: Have you got the code for this or an online reference? which version of ie?

Comment: yes for example they said you should do it like margin:0 auto; and some of them said margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a php guru but it seems very clear what those code do:

it insert the baseUrl constant in every stylesheet links

and load a right to left css if page has right to left text

```
<!--<?php if($this->direction == 'rtl') : ?> -->
```

Comment: thank you my friend but i thought it is a way to configure web page for another browser like IE or safari or opera. the main problem that i always have in web design is when make my content to be center with margin:auto; statement its only become center in Fire fox and not perform in IE what can i do for this???!

Comment: sorry i'm a developper not a webdesign. i cannot help you.